# Appending switch to a custom uninstaller

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, uninstallation

I have this custom uninstaller script that I made. The idea behind it is it's universal and is made to work with uninstalling msiexec as well as executable uninstallers (pulling the uninstall strings from the registry).
Now the caveat to this is; I'm noticing several msi installations have uninstall strings that show /I as a switch instead of /X; which doesn't make sense to me and I assume that's incorrect.

In my script I check to see if the parameter has /I and I replace it with /X.
Similarly, if the uninstall doesn't have a silent uninstall string, I am trying to append it into my uninstaller so it doesn't require any user interaction. When I try to append it, I get the msiexec window that comes up with all the switches; which tells me that the way I'm passing the switches is incorrect.

Here is an example when I try to uninstall Teams. I print out the variables for the uninstaller and the arguments passed.

Output looks like this (which tells me it should work):

```
MsiExec.exe 
/X{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B} /qn /norestart
```

I'm hoping someone can assist me. Here is my script.

```
CLS

$Software = "Teams"
$Filter = "*" + $Software + "*"
$Program = $ProgUninstall = $NULL

try 
{
    if (Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node") 
    {
        $programs = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    $programs += Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction Stop
    $programs += Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::\HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} 
catch
{
    Write-Error $_
    break
}

foreach($Program in $Programs)
{
    $ProgDisplayName = $Program.DisplayName
    $ProgUninstall = $Program.UninstallString

    if(($ProgDisplayName -like $Filter) -and ($NULL -ne $ProgUninstall))
    {

        $aux = $ProgUninstall -split @('\.exe'),2,[System.StringSplitOptions]::None
        $Uninstaller = (cmd /c echo $($aux[0].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'") + '.exe')).Trim('"')
        $UninsParams = $aux[1].TrimStart('"').TrimStart("'").Trim().split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

        if($UninsParams -like "/I*")
        {
            $UninsParams = $UninsParams -replace("/I", "/X")
        }

        
        if($Uninstaller -like "MsiExec.exe")
        {
            $UninsParams = "$UninsParams /qn /norestart"
        }
        
        
        #Debug
        $Uninstaller
        $UninsParams

        try
        {
            . $Uninstaller $UninsParams | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "param 0 = *" }
        }
        Catch
        {
            write-host "Unable to uninstall: " $Uninstaller $UninsParams
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "which doesn't make sense to me and I assume that's incorrect." - have you considered validating that assumption? :-)

Comment: I guess that's a valid question, but just looking at the msiexec windows installer properties, it shows you that /i or /package is for installation and /x or /uninstall is for uninstalls.

Edit:
Just checked and confirmed. I tried running the code manually based on what's in the registry: "MsiExec.exe /I{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B}" and it doesn't uninstall.

Comment: Also if I manually run this "MsiExec.exe /X{731F6BAA-A986-45A4-8936-7C3AAAAA760B} /qn /noreboot" it does silently uninstall without any user interaction, so it must be the way the parm is being passed in the script.

Comment: Instead of `/noreboot` you could try `REBOOT=ReallySuppress`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I do know that the parameters I pass manually work though because as I mentioned in my comment above yours when I type it in manually into cmd it does a full silent uninstall the way I want it to. It just doesn't seem to pass my switches in the script for some reason. Perhaps I need to change the way I call the uninstaller and try using start-process instead???

Comment: Your filtering makes me nervous! What if somebody had another app with 'teams' in the name installed? Your script would delete 'OmniCorp TeamShare' (fictional, I just made that up, but it sounds like it could be legit for document sharing with your team or something) just as fast as it uninstalled 'Microsoft Teams'.

Comment: That's a good point. In our environment we don't have anything like that, but I guess if there are apps with similar names, you would have to adjust the variable to be more fine tuned to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you create a string array at this line:

```
$aux = $ProgUninstall -split @('\.exe'),2,[System.StringSplitOptions]::None
```

So $aux is an array of strings, but you try to treat it like a single string later on. If you want it to act like a string not an array you'll need to join it at some point. Either that or don't use cmd to execute the uninstall and keep it as an array (that's what I'd do). If you want to keep it an array you could use `Start-Process` instead, and then add your arguments to the correct parameter. Something like:

```
foreach($Program in $Programs)
{
    $ProgDisplayName = $Program.DisplayName
    $ProgUninstall = $Program.UninstallString

    if(($ProgDisplayName -like $Filter) -and ($NULL -ne $ProgUninstall))
    {

        $aux = $ProgUninstall -split '(?<=\.exe[''"]?) ',2,[System.StringSplitOptions]::None
        $Uninstaller = $aux[0].trim('''"')
        $UninsParams = $aux[1].Trim() -split ' (?=/|-)',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries

        if($Uninstaller -eq "MsiExec.exe")
        {
            [string[]]$UninsParams = $UninsParams -replace "/I", "/X"
            [string[]]$UninsParams = $UninsParams|?{$_ -notin '/qn','/norestart'}
            [string[]]$UninsParams += '/qn'
            [string[]]$UninsParams += '/norestart'
        }
        
        
        #Debug
        $Uninstaller
        $UninsParams

        Try
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath $Uninstaller -ArgumentList $UninsParams
        }
        Catch
        {
            write-host "Unable to uninstall: $Uninstaller $UninsParams"
        }
    }
}
```

That'll split your parameters on a space followed by `/` or `-`, which should follow most things that take parameters. If you just want to do it on the spaces you could change the line to:

```
        $UninsParams = $aux[1].Trim() -split ' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it's working well for me.